# is any JavaScript statement an expression?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I know that functional languages like Lisp don't have statements. Everything there is an expression. JavaScript is a functional language. So I came to a conclusion that every JavaScript statement is an expression. This thought came to my mind when I was playing with chrome's console. Every statement entered there is evaluated and the console returns undefined if an expression doesn't return certain value.

Comment: http://www.2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html **and** http://www.yaldex.com/javascript_tutorial_2/LiB0027.html . Maybe I'm misunderstanding

Comment: I've read this article before. And I know the difference between statements and expressions. But in JavaScript the difference is a bit blurry, isn't it.

Comment: JavaScript is not really a functional language. It has bits of both, like Python or even PHP (since it has lambda function).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say no, as you can't use just any statement where an expression is expected:

```
// SyntaxError: Unexpected token var
var a = var b;
```

```
// SyntaxError: Unexpected token if
var c = if (true) {};
```

The `undefined` shown in Chrome's console is due to its use of [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) (or a native/internal equivalent), which evaluates any *code*:

```
var a = eval('var b;');
console.log(a); // undefined
```

The `undefined` isn't the result of `var b;`, but because `eval()` itself still has a return value -- whether the evaluated code supplied it or not.

Comment: Also `throw`, `return`, `break`, `continue`, `switch`, `case`, `goto`, `while`, `for`... Control statements are statements, not expressions. (If you want everything to be an expression, CoffeeScript gets pretty close.)

Comment: Thanks! I am not a big fan of languages interpreted to js, but I think I'll try CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 7):

> I came to a conclusion that every JavaScript statement is an expression

No, definitely not. The EcmaScript standard differentiates quite clearly between [Statements (§12)](http://es5.github.io/#x12) and [Expressions (§11)](http://es5.github.io/#x11).

Yet, what you are mistaking for expressions is the [Expression Statement (§12.4)](http://es5.github.io/#x12.4), which consists solely of an expression (and is delimited by a semicolon).